# ubuntu 16.04 LTS will not boot after instalation from live-usb

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the system will not boot. When I look in the boot menu, I see a ubuntu option, but selecting it turns the screen black and then returns me to the BIOS.

I have checked with gparted if ubuntu is really on there and has the boot flag. I also ran Boot repair to no avail. I tried to boot in legacy mode, but that didn't work either.

I ran out of ideas, any suggestions?

EDIT: I am using UEFI and (i think) GPT. I have 3 HDDs, 2 (empty) 8TBs and a smaller 500GB with ubuntu on it. According to gparted, I have 3 partition on the drive: 1 swap, 1 EFI and 1 ext4. booting into grub using the live-usb gives me this:

```
ls
(memdisk) (hd0) (hd1) (hd1,apple2) hd1,apple1) (hd1,msdos2)
```

the grub config looks like this:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=10
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.8.0-36-generic-advanced-da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.8.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-36-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.8.0-36-generic-init-upstart-da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.8.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.8.0-36-generic-recovery-da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.8.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=da9f609d-1f95-4c5f-b199-c93a5e125c8b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root BBC6-3302
chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root BBC6-3302
chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: I have no solution, but I do notice one *very* unusual thing in your configuration: GRUB seems to think that your `(hd1)` has a mix of Apple and MBR/MS-DOS partitions on it, if I'm interpreting the output correctly. Was one of your disks used in an old PPC-based Mac, or partitioned with the Apple Partition Map? If so, and if that disk isn't critical, I suggest removing it, at least temporarily. If that clears up the problem, you can look into it further.

Comment: It seems like some pre-installed software is interfering with the boot process.  It is weird I can not see it with gparted. The pre-installed software is supposed to make set-up easier, by providing a intstall choice between windows, red hat and openSUSE. No Unbuntu, so I installed it manually. Guess now I am forced to try openSUSE anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't see anything after selecting Ubuntu from the boot menu, then I would guess the disk mapping fails so it can't find the root partition. so it can't even load the kernel.

There are a couple of factors in the boot process which are not in your question. If you use UEFI and GPT or BIOS and MBR, if you have a separate boot partition. Posting your grub config may also help.

You can enter the grub rescue mode and try to figure out the disk mappings with 'ls' and then 'boot'. Details on GRUB troubleshooting are here.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

**EDIT**

I assume that it picks up the wrong harddisk. hd0 doesn't show partitions and the third (or fisrst) disk is missing. Maybe your EFI doesn't recognize it? In Ubunutu the disks are loaded by the kernel, but in the bootprocess it is Grub and EFI that load disks.

Grub tries to load modules for EFI support and if that works can load by UUID. UUID is a unique identifier for partitions. The harddisk order may be differt in Ubuntu then in EFI. Normally hd0,1 maps to /dev/sda1, but I assume for you hd0 is mapped to one of your other disks. Rob Smith's advice to disconnect the other disks makes sense. Otherwise you will have to manually fix the grub configuration to point to the right root disk where grub modules and the kernel are located. You can in the grub CLI experiment with the "set root=(hdX,Y)"  but that would only work if the disk is actually recognized in EFI